# Getting posts under the custom post type ui category

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories

I would like to get all the posts under a category (custom post type ui category) into a different template other than archive.php or category.php.

I tried normal way of getting the posts using category id, but it returns empty array. Please help.

Comment: why don't you share your code that you already tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Worked perfectly for me!!
Code will bring the posts(under CPT UI) to any page template.

```
    <?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'specialoffers', 
    'cat' => '12', // Whatever the category ID is for your aerial category
    'posts_per_page' =>  10,
    'orderby' => 'date', // Purely optional - just for some ordering
    'order' => 'DESC' // Ditto
) );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> custom post type ui category

It sounds like you might be referring to a **custom** taxonomy that you created with the "Custom Post Type UI" plugin. If that's the case, then you'll need to use a taxonomy template: `taxonomy.php`.

[Wordpress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)

`category.php` and `tag.php` are only used for the built-in "category" and "tag" taxonomies.